# Check if any app can handle URI scheme

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, uri

I'm creating a Windows Phone 8 app (Store apps) in which I will have some links for the user to open other apps. 
My goal is to hide or show only the links for which I have apps that can handle them.

For instance, I have a link for

```
mymoneyapp://user=123
```

and another for

```
mymusic://user=123
```

So, if I have an app that can handle the `mymoneyapp` scheme I want the link to show if not then I hide it.

The only why I found to test this is using

```
LauncherOptions options = LauncherOptions();
options.FallbackUri = new Uri("http://myfallbackpage.com");
Launcher.LauncherUriAsync(new Uri("mymoneyapp://user=123"), options);
```

But in this case I get my fallback Uri launched if no app can handle that schema.
Is there any way just to test if an app can launch it without actually do it?

Comment: Your application will have non root access,so it is not  possible access such kind of data. Also more than one app may have the same scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for this on Windows Phone 8. Windows 10 adds Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync to allow checking if there is a handler before launching it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.queryurisupportasync.aspx